# Array comparison not matching elementwise comparison in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I have a numpy array `arr`. It's a `numpy.ndarray`, size is `(5553110,)`, `dtype=float32`.

When I do:

```
(arr > np.pi )[3154950]
False
(arr[3154950] > np.pi )
True
```

Why is the first comparison getting it wrong? And how can I fix it?

The values:

```
arr[3154950]= 3.1415927
np.pi= 3.141592653589793
```

Is the problem with precision?

Comment: I'd be curious to see what the values of the 3 or so indices on each side of the index is (and the value at the index).

Comment: I've gone ahead and opened an issue in the numpy issues as well to see if we can get a clearer answer of what is happening in the backend of numpy. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10982

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is due to accuracy of `np.float32` vs `np.float64`.

Use `np.float64` and you will not see a problem:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([3.1415927], dtype=np.float64)

print((arr > np.pi)[0])  # True

print(arr[0] > np.pi)    # True
```

---

As @WarrenWeckesser comments:

> It involves how numpy decides to cast the arguments of its operations.
>   Apparently, with `arr > scalar`, the scalar is converted to the same
>   type as the array `arr`, which in this case is `np.float32`. On the other
>   hand, with something like `arr > arr2`, with both arguments nonscalar
>   arrays, they will use a common data type. That's why (`arr >
>   np.array([np.pi]))[3154950]` returns `True`.

[Related github issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10322)

Comment: Do the two indexing schemes change how the conversion is applied?

Comment: @GrantWilliams, That is my instinct. I believe conversion to `np.float32` is applied inconsistently in the 2 scenarios, hence leading to differences. I think we need a better answer.. OP, don't accept this one yet!

Comment: This is correct, thanks (but I shall wait)! I expected float 32 to be upgraded to float64 even for big arrays.

Comment: This is the most interesting problem i've seen all day. I'm really curious why they would be different. When converting the entire array into a boolean array and then indexing im curious if its done with np.float32 for efficiency reasons? Where as using array[index] > value might not need to be converted to a lower precision because its a single comparison. Definitely going to have to get deep in the docs to figure it out

Comment: It involves how numpy decides to cast the arguments of its operations.  Apparently, with `arr > scalar`, the scalar is converted to the same type as the array `arr`, which in this case is `np.float32`.  On the other hand,  with something like `arr > arr2`, with both arguments nonscalar arrays, they will use a common data type.  That's why `(arr > np.array([np.pi]))[3154950]` returns True.

Comment: Indeed, I added some data points to ponder. But I'd appreciate if someone found the answer (i.e. `numpy` "rationale" / priority logic) and posted it.. my one just provides a fix, not an explanation.

Comment: `np.float64(3.1415927) > np.float32(np.pi)  # False` is consistent because once you round up the number increasing precision doesn't decrease back the value

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Same as [this issue (maybe non-issue)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10322) right?

Comment: @miradulo Yep, that looks like the same issue.